How can I fix ts1005 error in package.json file?
I installed the react using vite, but in the package.json file installed with me, ts1005 error appears on each line, how do I fix this?

I've tried all the searches I can, such as reinstalling TypeScript, but they still don't fix it.
 {
  "name": "section04",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.66",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.22",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.34.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.6",
    "vite": "^5.2.0"
  }
}

